# in the below code, if last query is not returning reject_count(as there are no rejects in the table), if statement below this query is not executing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

1)In the below code, if the last query is not returning "reject_count"(as there are no rejects in the table) if the statement below this query is not executing.
Any alternative for this situation
2)if d_count value is empty, how do i check in the if condition, d_count=r_id

```
    create or replace procedure editor30 (p_title in paper.title%type,round_num in integer)
    is
    cursor c2 is
    select pv.decision,pv.rcomment from paper_review pv,paper p where p.pid=pv.pid and p.title=p_title and pv.round=round_num;
    
    r_decision integer;
    p_title1 paper.title%type;
    c integer;
    r_comment paper_review.rcomment%type;
    r_id integer;
    d_count integer;
    r_num integer;
    reject_count integer;
    
    begin
    select count(*) into c from paper where title=p_title;
    if c=0 then 
        dbms_output.put_line('No such paper');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(p_title||':');
        select count(distinct rid) into r_id from paper p,paper_review pv where p.pid=pv.pid and p.title=p_title and pv.round=round_num;
        dbms_output.put_line('total no of reviews in round '||round_num||' is :'||r_id);
        open c2;
            loop
                fetch c2 into r_decision,r_comment;
                exit when c2%notfound;
                dbms_output.put_line(r_decision ||'  ' ||r_comment);
            end loop;
        close c2;
        select count(decision) into d_count from paper p,paper_review pv where p.pid=pv.pid and pv.round=round_num and p.title=p_title and pv.decision=1 group by p.title,pv.round;
        dbms_output.put_line('total no of accepts :'||d_count); 
        select count(decision) into reject_count from paper p,paper_review pv where p.pid=pv.pid and pv.round=round_num and p.title=p_title and pv.decision=4 group by p.title,pv.round;
        dbms_output.put_line('total no of rejects :'||reject_count);
        if d_count=r_id then
            dbms_output.put_line('suggestion or the paper is accept');
        elsif reject_count>=2 then
            dbms_output.put_line('suggestion for the paper is reject');
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('suggestion to be decided by editor');
        end if;
    end if;
    exception 
    when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('');
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it looks as if you're misinterpreting what's going on.

First of all, remove `EXCEPTION` handler as it doesn't *handle* anything; it displays an empty string so you have no idea whether `NO_DATA_FOUND` happened or not. Or, at least, display something meaningful.

---

Then, `count` function will return `0` even there are no rows to be returned:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp, dept where 1 = 2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Therefore, saying that "query is not returning reject_count" or "d_count value is empty" is most probably wrong.

---

However, those queries have `group by` clauses which might raise `TOO_MANY_ROWS` as you're fetching count into scalar variables, and that just won't work:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp e, dept d group by e.deptno;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        24
        20
        12
```

There's no way to put 3 values (rows) into `reject_count` which is declared as `integer`.

---

> how do i check in the if condition, d_count=r_id

One option is to use `NVL` function, e.g.

```
if nvl(d_count, -1) = nvl(r_id, -1) then ...
```

---

Finally, do you see *anything* on the screen? Any output at all? If not, did you `set serveroutput on`?

For us, it is difficult to test code you wrote as we don't have your tables nor data. Consider creating test case for us (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements), explaining what result you expect out of it.